# Possible way to parse symbols into an integer calculation?

Tags: java

I am building a simple calculator application. I am using strings to store the users numbers. When clicking the numbered button, that number is added to the end of the string. For example

```
String num1;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    num1 = num1+"1";
} 
//this code is repeated for the rest of the buttons
```

So my final string num1 will be all of these digits added together which I can parse into an Integer later on. However for my addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division buttons, am I able to repeat the same code but instead of adding a number to the end, I would add the symbol corresponding to it and continue parsing it into an integer later on? Example:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    num1 = num1+"+";              //or -, *, / instead of +
}
```

Or will I have to create a separate variable for the symbol and add it separately in a different string function?

Comment: `Or will I have to create a separate variable for the symbol and add it separately in a different string function?` I'm afraid that there are a ton of ways to implement this and the question as such is just oo broad to be asked here :/

Comment: The only possible way (afaik) is to take a look at the char and determine whether it's an operation or not and then do stuff accordingly. Java (at least naively) doesn't have an eval function as javascript does.

Comment: BipoN There are a bunch of ways you can make this work. You could accumulate a string like "12+7", and evaluate it when the user clicks '='.  It would be a little bit tricky to evaluate. Have you given that any thought? Another way is you could have class variables num1, num2, and operation. When the user clicks "=", it would be easier to evaluate. Think about how you would like it to work.

Comment: You can first save all the inputs into a string with *Infix*, then convert it to *Postfix* for calculating its result.